# C++ stream log Objective-C objects

Tags: c++, iostream, objective-c++, ostream

I am trying to write a C++ stream logger that is capable of printing objective-C++ variables as well.
The problem is that I can't get it to compile because of the template type checking when calling the obj-c method that gives me the description of the object.

I'd like to have some ideas on how to make it happen.

Thanks

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
//for operator<< on obj-c objects
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

//SFINAE to get whether we have a obj-c class or not
template<class T> struct IsObjectiveCClass {
    using yesT = char (&)[10];
    using noT = char (&)[1];
    static yesT choose(id);
    static noT choose(...);
    static T make();
    enum { value = sizeof(choose(make())) == sizeof(yesT) };
};
#endif

class Logger {

...


        template <typename T>
        Logger &operator <<(T data) {
#if __OBJC__

            if (IsObjectiveCClass<T>::value) {
                ... How to cast (data to obj) without errors? ...    
                stream->ts << [[obj description] UTF8String];
            } else {
#endif
                stream->ts << data;
#if __OBJC__
            }
#endif
        }
```

Comment: how about make a specialize template function for `NSObject` or `id`? and have you tried `(__bridge id)` cast?

Comment: Indeed, the problem is that T can assume any type, and if the it is a C type the __bridge will not work. AFAIK __bridge can only convert between CoreFoundation and Foundation objects.

Comment: bridge cast works for `void *`

Comment: Imagine I have
Logger() << @"TEST";
Logger() << "TEST";
The NSString will complain that the cast should be (bridge void*) and the char* will complain that the cast should be (bridge id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this

```
template<typename T, typename V = bool>
struct is_objc_class : std::false_type { };

template<typename T>
struct is_objc_class<T,
typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<T, id>::value, bool>::type
> : std::true_type { };

template <
class T,
class = typename std::enable_if<is_objc_class<T>::value>::type
>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, T const & t) {
    stream << [[t description] UTF8String];
    return stream;
}

struct Logger
{
    Logger(std::ostream &s):stream(s){}
    std::ostream &stream;

    // for objc class
    template <class T>
    typename std::enable_if<is_objc_class<T>::value, Logger&>::type
    operator<< (T const & t) {
        stream << [[t description] UTF8String];
        return *this;
    }

    // for everything else
    template <class T>
    typename std::enable_if<!is_objc_class<T>::value, Logger &>::type
    operator<< (T const & t) {
        stream << t;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
    << is_objc_class<id>::value << std::endl
    << is_objc_class<int>::value << std::endl
    << is_objc_class<NSString *>::value << std::endl
    << @"test" << std::endl
    << @[@1] << std::endl
    ;

    Logger l(std::cout);

    l << @"test" << "test2" << @1 << 1;
}
```

Comment: Thats exactly it. Thank you so much